# I need to get rid of focus

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

How do i make focus disappear on:

```
<Textbox Name="Textbox1" />
```

Or, if i can't make focus go away where is it before anything is focused ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FocusManager to set focus to something else. I'm not sure when you want to change the focus or where in your code you want to make the call from, but I put a call to FocusManager in the code behind of a form and set its focus to itself and it seems to work fine.

e.g. if you add this to your KeyUp event your textbox will lose focus when you press a

```
    private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.A)
            FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, this);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting IsTabStop=False and Focusable=false?

you can check this also:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx

Comment: How do i set Textbox1 to false ? (i tried some things and didn't work)

Comment: this just disables the focus and than i can't use this textbox again and besides that it makes the focus thingy freeze.

Comment: You probably don't need Focusable=false that disables focus for the textbox entirely. What scenario do you have/want?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the focus with the GotFocus (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx) Event of the textbox

Comment: There is an example in the link @Drahakar sent you. Did you look at it?

Comment: this is the example (don't know what this should help me):Private Sub Control1_GotFocus(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) _ 
     Handles Control1.GotFocus

Console.WriteLine("You are in the Control.GotFocus event.")

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You can use SetFocusedElement property to set focus to some other control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx

Also check out FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope Method
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.setisfocusscope.aspx

Comment: and what exactly would i accomplish by doing that ?

Comment: ok you use SetIsFocusScope(TextBox1,false) property of Focus Manager this will make textbox out of focus scope which means focus wont come to that control for example Dim focuseScope2 As New StackPanel()
   FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope(focuseScope2, False)

Comment: this is System.Windows.Forms, i am wpf